# VBA Access - Update statement using In

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-update

I can't find out if the below is possible.  I want to run an update statement in one database from another database. I know that I can save a query and run that from the master database but I thought the below would be possible

```
UPDATE tblOne 
 INNER JOIN tblTwo 
    ON tblOne.[TID] = tblTwo.TID 
   SET tblTwo.PC = [tblOne].[PC] 
  from tblOne in 'C:\DB.mdb' ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I want to know what the format is for using 'In' as part of an 'Update' statement:

Comment: Where does the 'In 'C:\DB.mdb'' go in the following:  UPDATE table SET newvalue WHERE criteria;

Answer (score 1):

Per the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907(v=office.12).aspx), the `IN` clause is only compatible when used in conjunction with the `SELECT` statement (i.e. Select queries), `INSERT INTO` statement (i.e. Append queries), or `SELECT INTO` statement (i.e. Make Table queries) - it cannot be used as part of an `UPDATE` statement.

I would suggest that you import `tblOne` as a linked table in the database in which you intend to execute your `UPDATE` query - this will also result in improved performance over the use of the `IN` clause.

To link the table, select **Access Database** from the **Import** panel of the **External Data** ribbon tab, and then select the **Link** option from the wizard:

[image]

After the table has been linked, your `UPDATE` statement will become simply:

```
UPDATE 
    tblOne INNER JOIN tblTwo ON tblOne.TID = tblTwo.TID 
SET 
    tblTwo.PC = tblOne.PC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reverse what you’ve written because the table you’re updating needs to be the main table.

Try:

```
UPDATE tblTwo  
INNER JOIN tblOne ON tblOne.[TID] = tblTwo.TID  
SET tblTwo.PC = [tblOne].[PC] ;
```

Please note without a where clause you will be updating all rows.

Comment: The update statement works in the master db but I can't run it in the second database - so I need the 'In' to use the second database but I can't get the format of the statement correct.  I'm wondering if this isn't possible and that's why I've seen people using Insert Into to get the data into the second database

Comment: Are the databases on the same database server?